# separate clusters observable in ggplot through a vector? R

Tags: r, ggplot2, vector, cluster-analysis

```
 df <- data.frame(samples = c('A1','B1','C1','K3','L4','M5','N5','O5'),var1 = c('12','34','54','54','0.1','0.45','0.99','5'),var2 = c('16.5','26.5','21.2','19.8','2.98','3','1.99','2.65'))

ggplot(df,aes(var1,var2)) + geom_point(shape = 21, col = 'black', size = 4)
```

I want to differentiate the two clusters observable in the `ggplot`.

[image]

So three datapoints and five datapoints are in the two clusters I want to distinguish. I think that I can somehow do it through a vector that seperates both groups, but I do not know how exactly that can be done.

I would like to have a `df` with the cluster information at the end

```
  samples var1 var2    cluster
1      A1   12 16.5    1
2      B1   34 26.5    2
3      C1   54 21.2    2
4      K3   54 19.8    2
5      L4  0.1 2.98    1  
6      M5  0.45 3.00   2
7      N5  0.99 1.99   1
8      O5    5 2.65    2
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you look at what you've plotted, you will see that the x axis isn't in the correct order or properly spaced. That's because your data frame has quotes around the numbers. These are therefore effectively being plotted as evenly spaced factor levels. The clusters you are seeing aren't real in that case.

If you use actual numbers, your plot will look like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(samples = c('A1','B1','C1','K3','L4','M5','N5','O5'),
                 var1 = c(12, 34, 54, 54, 0.1, 0.45, 0.99, 5),
                 var2 = c(16.5, 26.5, 21.2, 19.8, 2.98, 3, 1.99, 2.65))

ggplot(df, aes(var1, var2)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4)
```

[image]

I think I can see one cluster in the bottom left of this picture, but I'm not convinced about the remaining points. In any case, you can split all these points into two clusters based on distance quite easily:

```
df$cluster <- factor(cutree(hclust(dist(df[-1])), k = 2))

df
#>   samples  var1  var2 cluster
#> 1      A1 12.00 16.50       1
#> 2      B1 34.00 26.50       2
#> 3      C1 54.00 21.20       2
#> 4      K3 54.00 19.80       2
#> 5      L4  0.10  2.98       1
#> 6      M5  0.45  3.00       1
#> 7      N5  0.99  1.99       1
#> 8      O5  5.00  2.65       1
```

And you can plot it like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(var1, var2)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = cluster), shape = 21, size = 4)
```

[image]